# How to remove or disable Preloader in Wordpress Theme?

Tags: wordpress, preloader

I have bought a theme from themeforest, I just want to remove/disable preloader from it, Below is the link of the wordpress theme.

http://demo.thewebsitedev.com/offshore/

Comment: set this class `loaded` at `body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Appearance>customize>Additional CSS and Try

```
#preloader{display:none !important;}
```

Answer (score 2):

goto **APPEARANCE** }**Customize** **Additional css** then add the code below

```
#preloader{display:none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put this css on your custom css, this should work,

```
body > .preloader{ display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set class `loaded` on your `body` tag on `document.ready` event. Like that

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("body").addClass("loaded"); // that is :)
    //Preloader Effect  
    //code
});
```